# Automation Tests using DevExpress Grids with WatiN

Tags: devexpress, automated-tests, watin

I am currently using DevExpress grids

and I am now writing automation tests using WatiN, the problem I'm having is
adding and removing columns functionality. I was able to drag and drop the column but does not seem to work, looks like when WatiN talks to the DOM the devexpress javascript methods do not get run.

Anybody been able to get this to work?

Or know a way to add/remove (hide/show) columns in devexpress via javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we have not tried WatiN and thus, cannot suggest a solution to this problem.  However, please note, that the grid is a pure server side control.  It means, that its rendering is done on the server.  I.e. when you hide / add a new column in the client side, the request(callback) is sent to the server.  Anyway, there is a way to hide / show columns using java script using the gridView's client side [MoveColumn](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_MoveColumntopic) method.  **NOTE**, this method just sends a callback to the server and thus it will result in a server request.  Finally, the complete ASPxGridView client side API is published at:

[ASPxClientGridView Members](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridViewMembersTopicAll)

Comment: I will try that... I also tried using a "secret" callback I can pass a column name to that attempts to make column visible and do a call back, but doesnt show it

Comment: I do not know whether this system allows you to handle server side events.  However, the grid allows you to send a callback using the client side PerformCallback method and change the grid configuration as required, within its CustomCallback event handler.

Comment: OMG that worked.. THANKS big time!  just did a RunScript("GridName.MoveColumn('FieldName', 0);");